# Arduino voltage connection pins

Tags: pins, voltage, connector

On the Arduino power connector jack, which is the positive terminal pin and the negative pin?

Comment: Center-positive. On the UNO there is a diode, to protect against wrong polarity.

Comment: Here is more info about Arduinos power jack, https://learn.adafruit.com/ladyadas-learn-arduino-lesson-number-0/power-jack-and-supply

Answer (score 3):

Arduino's power connector jack's tip is positive while the sleeve is negative but the more important thing to know is what will you be using in powering Arduino? Please provide more information about your setup and possibly a schematic. This will help us understand more what you're trying to accomplish.